# Removing permalink from post thumb in twentyeleven

Tags: functions, theme-twenty-eleven, the-content

possibly a simple thing to do but I'm not sure how it's done - I want to remove the permalink from a post thumb, in the default twentyeleven theme. Looked through content.php and the other templates and I can't see where to do this - is this something which should be handled as a custom filter in functions.php?

Comment: You're to have to be more specific about where you want to remove the permalink.  In the showcase template? Archive page?  Single post pages? Post thumbnails are used in several places on that theme.

Answer (score 1):

No idea, never used twenty eleven theme. I opened the theme files. Check out showcase.php around Line 104-118.

Should be on line 115 - just remove the anchor wrapping the post thumb,

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail_size ); ?></a>
```